# Is there a list of all display functions for templates?

Tags: theme-development, references

I am going to write my own post display thing, and I cannot find a list of all these type of functions:

```
the_date();
the_title();  
the_excerpt();
```

I'm sure there are more, but where can I find a list?

Comment: Adola, what exactly is your question. As it stands, my answer doesn't answer your question, but you've marked it as such. Now, you need to consider — re-editing your question, OR unmarking my answer. :)

Comment: I cannot understand how this question is either not constructive, or has no answer. 

I clearly asked a simple question, where can I find more of these functions.  

I found them by using a tutorial, Aahan Krish's answer gave the direction I needed. 

To close this question is both irritating, and clearly misguided.

Comment: Your question is just not specific enough. A simple [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+the_excerpt()) answers it already. Plus, you are asking for a List Of Things – something we really want to avoid. See [here](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1033/73) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#1)** A doc for a function on **[WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/)** lists all related functions at the bottom of the page. For example, [this is the doc for `the_date();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) — look at the section highlighted in the screenshot below:

<sub>**Click on the image to enlarge...**</sub>

[image: Screenshot]

**#2)** Another very good reference is [**QueryPosts**](http://queryposts.com/). When you search for a function on QueryPosts, you can presume that the search results are related to that function (at least in most cases). For example:

<sub>**Click on the image to enlarge...**</sub>

[image: Screenshot 2]

Now, for the sake of relevance, here go the links to the pages for the respective functions where you can find other functions related to them:

- **`the_date();`** — [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date), [QueryPosts](http://queryposts.com/?s=the_date)
- **`the_title();`** — [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), [QueryPosts](http://queryposts.com/?s=the_title)
- **`the_excerpt();`** — [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt), [QueryPosts](http://queryposts.com/?s=the_excerpt)

And then there's Google. For e.g. [`the_date();` on Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=wordpress%20the_date)

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is the [Wordpress Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference), [the template tags list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags), or the even the [Wordpress source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser).

Answer (score 1):

@Rarst built a wonderful tool for this, named [queryposts](http://queryposts.com/).

*Disclaimer: I know this isn't a good answer, as too short, but I close vote anyway :)*